# Recycler View with multiple adapter and viewtype not working

Tags: java, android, android-layout, android-recyclerview, adapter

This is my required prototype:
[image]
What result I am getting
[image]

I am trying this with multiple viewtype in single RecylerView but I am not getting required result. And not getting what logic need to write if using `getItemViewType()`. Please help me out

This is JSON Data which I want to implement into RecylerView

```
 {
  "rows": [{
    "sequence_id":1,
    "sequence_description":"animal description goes here",
    "sequence_image":"thumbnail.png",
    "sequence_title": "Animal",    
    "child_rows":[
      {
        "id": "1",
        "name":"Lion",
        "description" : "lion description goes here",
        "image": "Lion.png"

      },
      {
        "id": "2",
        "name":"Tiger",
        "description" : "Tiger description goes here",
        "image": "Tiger.png"
      },
      {
        "id": "3",
        "name":"Elephant",
        "description" : "Elephant description goes here",
        "image": "Elephant.png"
      }       
      ]
  },
{
    "sequence_id":2,
    "sequence_description":"animal description goes here",
    "sequence_image":"thumbnail.png",
    "sequence_title": "Birds",    
    "child_rows":[
      {
        "id": "1",
        "name":"Parrot",
        "description" : "Parrot description goes here",
        "image": "parrot.png"
      },
      {
        "id": "2",
        "name":"Pigeon",
        "description" : "Pigeon description goes here",
        "image": "Pigeon.png"
      },
      {
       "id": "3",
        "name":"Crow",
        "description" : "Crow description goes here",
        "image": "crow.png"
      }       
      ]
  }  
  ]
}
```

**Activity.java**

```
 mrecyclerview = (RecyclerView) findViewById(R.id.recyclerView);
        try {
            JSONObject jsonObj = new JSONObject(dataStr.getJsonString());


            JSONArray jsondata = jsonObj.getJSONArray("rows");


            for(int i = 0;i<jsondata.length();i++){
                JSONObject rowsdata = jsondata.getJSONObject(i);

                Integer sequence_id = rowsdata.getInt("sequence_id");
                String sequence_description = rowsdata.getString("sequence_description");
                String sequence_image = rowsdata.getString("sequence_image");
                String sequence_title = rowsdata.getString("sequence_title");



                List<ScreenOneInventory> minventorylist = new ArrayList<ScreenOneInventory>();
                ScreenOneRows soRows = new ScreenOneRows();
                JSONArray childres = rowsdata.getJSONArray("child_rows");
                for(int j =0;j<childres.length();j++){
                    JSONObject inventorydata = childres.getJSONObject(j);
                    Log.i("Fragment","I am here in loop j:"+j);
                    String id = inventorydata.getString("id");
                    String name = inventorydata.getString("name");
                    String description = inventorydata.getString("description");
                    String image = inventorydata.getString("image");


                    ScreenOneInventory soinventoryObj = new ScreenOneInventory();
                    soinventoryObj.setId(id);
                    soinventoryObj.setname(name);
                    soinventoryObj.setDescription(description);
                    soinventoryObj.setImage(image);

                    minventorylist.add(soinventoryObj);


                }


                soRows.setSequence_id(sequence_id);
                soRows.setSequence_Description(sequence_description);
                soRows.setSequence_image(sequence_image);
                soRows.setSop_title(sequence_title);

                soRows.setInventoryList(minventorylist);

                RowsData.add(soRows);



            }



        } catch (JSONException e) {
            e.printStackTrace();
        }


        mrecyclerview.setLayoutManager(new LinearLayoutManager(getActivity()));
        ScreenOneAdapter adapter = new ScreenOneAdapter(getActivity(),RowsData,mrecyclerview);
        mrecyclerview.setAdapter(adapter);
}
```

This is My Parent Rows adapter  **ScreenOneAdapter.java**

```
public class ScreenOneAdapter extends RecyclerView.Adapter<ScreenOneAdapter.BaseViewHolder> {

    private LayoutInflater mInflater;
    private List<ScreenOneRows> mRowsList;
    public static final int PARENT_VIEW = 0;
    public static final int CHILD_VIEW = 1;
    private RecyclerView recyclerView;
            private Context mcontext;
    public ScreenOneAdapter(Context context, List<ScreenOneRows> mRowsList, RecyclerView mrecyclerview) {
        this.mInflater = LayoutInflater.from(context);
        this.mRowsList = mRowsList;
        this.recyclerView = mrecyclerview;
        this.mcontext = context;
    }

    @Override
    public BaseViewHolder onCreateViewHolder(ViewGroup parent, int viewType) {
        View view;


                view = mInflater.inflate(R.layout.list_item_rows,parent,false);
                RowsListHolder rowHolder = new RowsListHolder(view);
                return rowHolder;



    }

    @Override
    public void onBindViewHolder(BaseViewHolder holder, int position) {
        ScreenOneRows current = mRowsList.get(position);


        RowsListHolder rHolder =  (RowsListHolder) holder;
        rHolder.setData(current);
        List mInventoryList = current.getInventoryList();

       InventoryListAdapter iadapter = new InventoryListAdapter(mcontext,mInventoryList);
        recyclerView.setAdapter(iadapter);
    }

    @Override
    public int getItemCount() {
        return (null != mRowsList ? mRowsList.size() : 0);
    }




    public class BaseViewHolder extends RecyclerView.ViewHolder{

        public BaseViewHolder(View itemView) {
            super(itemView);
        }
    }

    public class RowsListHolder extends BaseViewHolder{
      private   ImageView icon;
      private TextView title;
      private TextView description;

        public RowsListHolder(View itemView) {
            super(itemView);

            icon = (ImageView) itemView.findViewById(R.id.img_icon);
            title = (TextView) itemView.findViewById(R.id.tvTitle);
            description = (TextView) itemView.findViewById(R.id.tvDescription);
        }
        public void setData(ScreenOneRows current){
            this.title.setText(current.getSequence_title());
            this.description.setText(current.getSequence_description());
        }


    }


}
```

This is my child rows adapter **InventoryListAdapter.java**

```
public class InventoryListAdapter extends RecyclerView.Adapter<InventoryListAdapter.InventoryListHolder> {

    private List<ScreenOneInventory> mInventoryList;
    private LayoutInflater mInflater;
    public InventoryListAdapter(Context context, List<ScreenOneInventory> mInventoryList) {
        this.mInventoryList = mInventoryList;
        this.mInflater = LayoutInflater.from(context);
    }

    @Override
    public InventoryListAdapter.InventoryListHolder onCreateViewHolder(ViewGroup parent, int viewType) {
        View rootView;
        rootView = mInflater.inflate(R.layout.list_item_inventory,parent,false);
        InventoryListHolder invHolder = new InventoryListHolder(rootView);
        return invHolder;
    }

    @Override
    public void onBindViewHolder(InventoryListAdapter.InventoryListHolder holder, int position) {
       ScreenOneInventory currentInv = mInventoryList.get(position);
        InventoryListHolder invenHolder = (InventoryListHolder) holder;
        invenHolder.setData(currentInv);
    }

    @Override
    public int getItemCount() {
        return (null != mInventoryList ? mInventoryList.size() : 0);
    }

    public class InventoryListHolder extends RecyclerView.ViewHolder {
      private ImageView imgicon;
     private TextView title;
     private TextView description;
        public InventoryListHolder(View itemView) {
            super(itemView);
            imgicon = (ImageView) itemView.findViewById(R.id.img_inv_icon);
            title = (TextView) itemView.findViewById(R.id.titletxt);
            description = (TextView) itemView.findViewById(R.id.descriptiontxt);
        }

        public void setData(ScreenOneInventory data) {
            this.title.setText(data.getName());
            this.status.setText(data.getDescription());
        }
    }
}
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

There is no need to create the Two different adapter You can use two different item layout in case of Row and child.

you need to create One common list view with a extra info like this value is row value or child value.
if row value is true inflate the item_row.xml
if row value is false inflate the item_child.xml

I have created the sample application You can copy paste and check

**Main Activity **

```
public class MainActivity extends AppCompatActivity {
List<ScreenOneInventory> minventorylist = new ArrayList<ScreenOneInventory>();
List<ScreenOneRows> screenOneRowses = new ArrayList<>();
ArrayList<ItemInterface> finalList = new ArrayList<>();

@Override
protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
    setContentView(R.layout.activity_main);
    String dataStr = "{\n" +
            "  \"rows\": [{\n" +
            "    \"sequence_id\":1,\n" +
            "    \"sequence_description\":\"animal description goes here\",\n" +
            "    \"sequence_image\":\"thumbnail.png\",\n" +
            "    \"sequence_title\": \"Animal\",    \n" +
            "    \"child_rows\":[\n" +
            "      {\n" +
            "        \"id\": \"1\",\n" +
            "        \"name\":\"Lion\",\n" +
            "        \"description\" : \"lion description goes here\",\n" +
            "        \"image\": \"Lion.png\"\n" +
            "\n" +
            "      },\n" +
            "      {\n" +
            "        \"id\": \"2\",\n" +
            "        \"name\":\"Tiger\",\n" +
            "        \"description\" : \"Tiger description goes here\",\n" +
            "        \"image\": \"Tiger.png\"\n" +
            "      },\n" +
            "      {\n" +
            "        \"id\": \"3\",\n" +
            "        \"name\":\"Elephant\",\n" +
            "        \"description\" : \"Elephant description goes here\",\n" +
            "        \"image\": \"Elephant.png\"\n" +
            "      }       \n" +
            "      ]\n" +
            "  },\n" +
            "{\n" +
            "    \"sequence_id\":2,\n" +
            "    \"sequence_description\":\"animal description goes here\",\n" +
            "    \"sequence_image\":\"thumbnail.png\",\n" +
            "    \"sequence_title\": \"Birds\",    \n" +
            "    \"child_rows\":[\n" +
            "      {\n" +
            "        \"id\": \"1\",\n" +
            "        \"name\":\"Parrot\",\n" +
            "        \"description\" : \"Parrot description goes here\",\n" +
            "        \"image\": \"parrot.png\"\n" +
            "      },\n" +
            "      {\n" +
            "        \"id\": \"2\",\n" +
            "        \"name\":\"Pigeon\",\n" +
            "        \"description\" : \"Pigeon description goes here\",\n" +
            "        \"image\": \"Pigeon.png\"\n" +
            "      },\n" +
            "      {\n" +
            "       \"id\": \"3\",\n" +
            "        \"name\":\"Crow\",\n" +
            "        \"description\" : \"Crow description goes here\",\n" +
            "        \"image\": \"crow.png\"\n" +
            "      }       \n" +
            "      ]\n" +
            "  }  \n" +
            "  ]\n" +
            "}";


    try {
        JSONObject jsonObj = new JSONObject(dataStr);


        JSONArray jsondata = jsonObj.getJSONArray("rows");


        for (int i = 0; i < jsondata.length(); i++) {
            JSONObject rowsdata = jsondata.getJSONObject(i);

            String sequence_id = rowsdata.getString("sequence_id");
            String sequence_description = rowsdata.getString("sequence_description");
            String sequence_image = rowsdata.getString("sequence_image");
            String sequence_title = rowsdata.getString("sequence_title");

            ScreenOneRows soRows = new ScreenOneRows();
            soRows.setSequence_id(sequence_id);
            soRows.setSequence_description(sequence_description);
            soRows.setSequence_image(sequence_image);
            soRows.setSequence_title(sequence_title);
            finalList.add(soRows);

            JSONArray childres = rowsdata.getJSONArray("child_rows");
            for (int j = 0; j < childres.length(); j++) {
                JSONObject inventorydata = childres.getJSONObject(j);
                Log.i("Fragment", "I am here in loop j:" + j);
                String id = inventorydata.getString("id");
                String name = inventorydata.getString("name");
                String description = inventorydata.getString("description");
                String image = inventorydata.getString("image");

                ScreenOneInventory soinventoryObj = new ScreenOneInventory();
                soinventoryObj.setId(id);
                soinventoryObj.setName(name);
                soinventoryObj.setDescription(description);
                soinventoryObj.setImage(image);
                finalList.add(soinventoryObj);

            }

        }

        RecyclerView recyclerView = (RecyclerView) findViewById(R.id.rv);
        recyclerView.setHasFixedSize(true);
        RecyclerView.LayoutManager mLayoutManager = new LinearLayoutManager(this);
        recyclerView.setLayoutManager(mLayoutManager);
        MyCustomAdapter myCustomAdapter = new MyCustomAdapter(finalList, this);
        recyclerView.setAdapter(myCustomAdapter);
    } catch (Exception e) {
        e.printStackTrace();
    }

}
}
```

**Entity classes**

**ScreenOneInventory**

```
class ScreenOneInventory implements ItemInterface {
String id;
String name;
String description;
String image;

public String getId() {
    return id;
}

public void setId(String id) {
    this.id = id;
}

public String getName() {
    return name;
}

public void setName(String name) {
    this.name = name;
}

public String getDescription() {
    return description;
}

public void setDescription(String description) {
    this.description = description;
}

public String getImage() {
    return image;
}

public void setImage(String image) {
    this.image = image;
}

@Override
public boolean isRow() {
    return false;
}
}
```

**ScreenOneRows.java**

```
class ScreenOneRows implements ItemInterface{
String sequence_id;
String sequence_description;
String sequence_image;
String sequence_title;

public String getSequence_id() {
    return sequence_id;
}

public void setSequence_id(String sequence_id) {
    this.sequence_id = sequence_id;
}

public String getSequence_description() {
    return sequence_description;
}

public void setSequence_description(String sequence_description) {
    this.sequence_description = sequence_description;
}

public String getSequence_image() {
    return sequence_image;
}

public void setSequence_image(String sequence_image) {
    this.sequence_image = sequence_image;
}

public String getSequence_title() {
    return sequence_title;
}

public void setSequence_title(String sequence_title) {
    this.sequence_title = sequence_title;
}

@Override
public boolean isRow() {
    return true;
}
}
```

**Recycler view Adapter **
** MyCustomAdapter.java**

```
public class MyCustomAdapter extends RecyclerView.Adapter<RecyclerView.ViewHolder> {

public static final int ROW_VIEW = 0;
public static final int CHILD_VIEW = 1;

ArrayList<ItemInterface> finalList;
WeakReference<Context> mContextWeakReference;

public MyCustomAdapter(ArrayList<ItemInterface> finalList, Context context) {
    this.finalList = finalList;
    this.mContextWeakReference = new WeakReference<Context>(context);
}

@Override
public RecyclerView.ViewHolder onCreateViewHolder(ViewGroup parent, int viewType) {

    Context context = mContextWeakReference.get();
    if (viewType == ROW_VIEW) {
        return new SectionViewHolder(LayoutInflater.from(parent.getContext()).inflate(R.layout.item_row, parent, false));
    }
    return new MyViewHolder(LayoutInflater.from(parent.getContext()).inflate(R.layout.item_child, parent, false), context);
}

@Override
public int getItemViewType(int position) {
    if (finalList.get(position).isRow()) {
        return ROW_VIEW;
    } else {
        return CHILD_VIEW;
    }
}

@Override
public void onBindViewHolder(final RecyclerView.ViewHolder holder, int position) {

    Context context = mContextWeakReference.get();

    if (context == null) {
        return;
    }

    if (ROW_VIEW == getItemViewType(position)) {

        SectionViewHolder sectionViewHolder = (SectionViewHolder) holder;
        ScreenOneRows screenOneRows = (ScreenOneRows) finalList.get(position);
        sectionViewHolder.textView.setText(screenOneRows.getSequence_title());
        sectionViewHolder.textView2.setText(screenOneRows.getSequence_description());
        return;
    }

    MyViewHolder myViewHolder = (MyViewHolder) holder;
    ScreenOneInventory childInventory = (ScreenOneInventory) finalList.get(position);
    myViewHolder.textView.setText(childInventory.getName());
    myViewHolder.textView2.setText(childInventory.getDescription());

}


@Override
public int getItemCount() {
    //return mUsersAndSectionList.size();
    return finalList.size();
}

//holder
public class MyViewHolder extends RecyclerView.ViewHolder {

    TextView textView, textView2;
    ImageView image;

    public MyViewHolder(View itemView, final Context context) {

        super(itemView);
        textView = itemView.findViewById(R.id.textView);
        textView2 = itemView.findViewById(R.id.textView2);
        image = itemView.findViewById(R.id.image);
    }
}

public class SectionViewHolder extends RecyclerView.ViewHolder {
    TextView textView, textView2;
    ImageView image;

    public SectionViewHolder(View itemView) {
        super(itemView);
        textView = itemView.findViewById(R.id.textView);
        textView2 = itemView.findViewById(R.id.textView2);
        image = itemView.findViewById(R.id.image);
    }


 }
```

**ItemInterface.java**
this class is used to make generic type of arraylist which can be infate using one adapter

```
public interface ItemInterface{
    boolean isRow();
```

}

**activity_main.xml**

```
<RelativeLayout android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="match_parent"
    tools:context="com.my.stackoverflowrecyclerview.MainActivity"
    xmlns:tools="http://schemas.android.com/tools"
    xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android">
    <android.support.v7.widget.RecyclerView
        android:id="@+id/rv"
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="match_parent"
        android:background="@color/bg"
         />
</RelativeLayout>
```

**item_row.xml**

```
<RelativeLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="70dp"
    android:layout_marginStart="50dp"
    android:background="#FFF"
    android:orientation="vertical"
    >

    <ImageView
        android:id="@+id/image"
        android:layout_width="70dp"
        android:layout_height="70dp"
        android:background="@mipmap/ic_launcher_round"/>

    <TextView
        android:id="@+id/textView"
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:layout_alignParentTop="true"
        android:layout_toEndOf="@+id/image"
        android:text="TextView" />

    <TextView
        android:id="@+id/textView2"
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:layout_alignParentBottom="true"
        android:layout_marginBottom="12dp"
        android:layout_toEndOf="@+id/image"
        android:text="TextView" />

</RelativeLayout>
```

**item_child.xml**

```
<RelativeLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="70dp"
    android:layout_marginStart="50dp"
    android:background="#FFF"
    android:orientation="vertical"
    >

    <ImageView
        android:id="@+id/image"
        android:layout_width="70dp"
        android:layout_height="70dp"
        android:background="@mipmap/ic_launcher_round"/>

    <TextView
        android:id="@+id/textView"
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:layout_alignParentTop="true"
        android:layout_toEndOf="@+id/image"
        android:text="TextView" />

    <TextView
        android:id="@+id/textView2"
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:layout_alignParentBottom="true"
        android:layout_marginBottom="12dp"
        android:layout_toEndOf="@+id/image"
        android:text="TextView" />

</RelativeLayout>
```

here is output[image]

Comment: Thanks a lot @MKY:)